# How can I access a constant of an inner class from a function definition?

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have the class `sprite` with the inner class `type`.

```
class sprite:
    class type:
        ThisValue = 10
        OtherValue = 22

    def __init__(self, type = sprite.type.ThisValue):
        self.type = type
```

When I try this, it says that the name `sprite` is not defined; the error throws on the `def __init__()` line. How can I access `ThisValue` in the function definition? Is there a better way to write the `type` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just

```
def __init__(self, type = type.ThisValue):
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm dumb for not thinking about that haha

Comment: @Tanner H. Please note, that same names for class and parameter is generally bad idea. Better to rename `class type` to something like `class type_cls` or rename method argument.